# How to increase the thickness of the line downward and upward with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

By default, the thickness of the line is spreading from the center (original path) to the left side and the right side. [See this image](https://ibb.co/0jrRPsZ), as you can see there, consider the white line is the original path and the black line which overlaps with the white line is the thickness.

My question: How to change the direction of spreading the thickness downward and upward?

The reason I'm asking this is because of when I draw a closed path inscribed in another closed path it becomes like [this](https://ibb.co/ZSrn4sY). I want the closed path inside has thickness in downward direction of the original path and the outside has thickness in upward direction of the original path, so my image would look nice.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    parallel segment/.style={
        segment distance/.store in=\segDistance,
        segment pos/.store in=\segPos,
        segment length/.store in=\segLength,
        to path={
            ($(\tikztostart)!\segPos!(\tikztotarget)!\segLength/2!(\tikztostart)!\segDistance!90:(\tikztotarget)$) -- 
            ($(\tikztostart)!\segPos!(\tikztotarget)!\segLength/2!(\tikztotarget)!\segDistance!-90:(\tikztostart)$)  \tikztonodes
        }, 
        % Default values
        segment pos=.5,
        segment length=1cm,
        segment distance=-2.5mm,
    },
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (7,1);
        \coordinate (C) at (3.5,4);
        \coordinate (D) at (3.5,.5);
        \coordinate (E) at (5.25,2.5);
        \coordinate (F) at (1.75,2);
        \draw [line width=3pt] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle
        node[] at (1.7,.8){$\bm{C}$};
        \draw [line width=3pt] (D)--(E)--(F)--cycle;
        \draw[->, line width=1.5pt, red] (A) to[parallel segment] (B);
        \draw[->, line width=1.5pt, red] (B) to[parallel segment] (C);
        \draw[->, line width=1.5pt, red] (C) to[parallel segment] (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to clip the plot.  If you use the same shape to clip and draw, only the inner half of each line will be visible.

The following simply clips off the excess corners.

[image: demo]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    parallel segment/.style={
        segment distance/.store in=\segDistance,
        segment pos/.store in=\segPos,
        segment length/.store in=\segLength,
        to path={
            ($(\tikztostart)!\segPos!(\tikztotarget)!\segLength/2!(\tikztostart)!\segDistance!90:(\tikztotarget)$) -- 
            ($(\tikztostart)!\segPos!(\tikztotarget)!\segLength/2!(\tikztotarget)!\segDistance!-90:(\tikztostart)$)  \tikztonodes
        }, 
        % Default values
        segment pos=.5,
        segment length=1cm,
        segment distance=-2.5mm,
    },
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex]
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (7,1);
        \coordinate (C) at (3.5,4);
        \coordinate (D) at (3.5,.5);
        \coordinate (E) at (5.25,2.5);
        \coordinate (F) at (1.75,2);
        \draw [line width=3pt] (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle
        node[] at (1.7,.8){$\bm{C}$};
        \begin{scope}
          \clip (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
          \draw [line width=3pt] (D)--(E)--(F)--cycle;
        \end{scope}
        \draw[->, line width=1.5pt, red] (A) to[parallel segment] (B);
        \draw[->, line width=1.5pt, red] (B) to[parallel segment] (C);
        \draw[->, line width=1.5pt, red] (C) to[parallel segment] (A);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```